# Getting text inside flexbox container to wrap and overflow: auto working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evanF/bdon7ytg/19/

I have a flexbox `container` `<div id="specialGameMessages">` and want the text inside to wrap when it gets too long, but I don't want the `height` of the `container` to increase, so when there's too much text, instead overflow: auto kicks in and makes it scrollable.

My problem currently is that the `flexbox` `container` expands in width and pushes everything off screen, without word-wrapping and overflow doesn't work.

I've tried messing around with the flex grow shrink basis properties but it doesn't work.

Also, I'm not sure if I even need the flex container to be flex (?)

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container1">
        <div id="websiteTitle">
            Design
        </div>

        <div id="gameTitle">
            MySite
        </div>

        <div id="specialGameMessages">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.   
        </div>

        <div id="navBarButtons">
            <button>Button1</button>
            <button>Button2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container1 {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 5vh;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #66d9ff;
}

#specialGameMessages {
    display: flex;
    flex: 5 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    overflow: auto;
    word-break: break-word;
    max-height: 23vh;
}
```

I just want the flex-container 1 to be one row long and if extra rows need to be added in specialGameMessages, then overflow will kick in. Also, no increase in width of container. Thanks!

Comment: add `flex-wrap: wrap` to container

Comment: @subham-gupta, thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: Remove ```flex: 5 0 auto``` and use ```flex-wrap: wrap```

Comment: use `flex: 1 1 auto` for your class specialGameMessages